# Check if C preprocessor macro defined in expression

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Motivation: I'm trying to define a template parameter based on whether or not a certain macro is defined. If the macro is defined, the template will select a different specialisation. I could put the whole specialisation in a huge `#ifdef` but I'm looking for perhaps a simpler way of doing it.

Question: Is there a way to check if a macro is defined in an expression ie without using `#ifdef`? This is what I mean:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << CHECK(macro) << " should print 0\n";
#define macro
    std::cout << CHECK(macro) << " should print 1\n";
#undef macro
#define macro 1
    std::cout << CHECK(macro) << " should print 1\n";
#undef macro
#define macro ""
    std::cout << CHECK(macro) << " should print 1\n";
#undef macro
    std::cout << CHECK(macro) << " should print 0\n";
}
```

So far I got two options, this does it at runtime:

```
#define CHECK_HELPER(x, y) (strcmp(#x, y) != 0)
#define CHECK(x) CHECK_HELPER(x, #x)
```

and this does it at compile-time, but not very nicely:

```
#define CHECK_HELPER(...) (#__VA_ARGS__[0] == '1' || #__VA_ARGS__[0] == '\0')
#define CHECK(...) CHECK_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: SOunds like an XY-problem. State what you want to achieve, not just **how**

Comment: @Olaf, why XY-problem? I guess the OP is looking for a nice implementation of CHECK in those "should print" statements. So we have a test case and can suggest an implementation. Though, it's a duplicate :)

Comment: @gavv: The question has the haut-gout of an XY-problem. Without clarifying what I requested we can't know for sure, though.

Comment: I think @Olaf means I didn't specify my motive, I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: @Giovanni, isn't [`is_set`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10119699/3169754) macro from the question I linked what you're looking for?

Comment: Almost, thanks for point it out. I think a combination of is_set and [DEFINED](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5465352/55935) does 99% of what I wanted (the case `#define macro ""` still doesn't work).